# Inherence of full measure sets from a Lie group to its homogeneous space.

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Haar measure $\mu$ and $\Gamma$ be a lattice of $G$. Namely $\Gamma$ is a closed discrete subgroup of $G$ with $G/\Gamma$ admitting a left $G$-invariant probability measure $\nu$. Let $U$ be any subset of $G$ with full Haar measure, namely $\mu(G-U)=0$. Let $x\in G/\Gamma$, a point in the homogeneous space. I wonder if it is necessarily true that $Ux$ also has full $\nu$ measure.

$$\nu(G/\Gamma - Ux)=0.$$

Or at least, $\nu (G/\Gamma - Ux)=0$ for $\nu$-almost every $x\in G/\Gamma$?

Comment: If you don't like the differential forms approach, I think Theorem 2.68 in Folland's harmonic analysis 2ed might be relevant. Perhaps it is similar to what you wrote down below.

Answer (score 0):

I have a proof when $\Gamma$ is a unimodular lattice in the Lie group $G$:

Since $G$ is a Lie group, thus second countable, as a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ must be countable.

Let $U$ be any subset of $G$ with full Haar measure. Now by the Theorem 1.5.3 (Quotient Integral Formula, $f$ there can be any $L^1$ function on $G$. Take $f=1_{(G-U)g_0}$, noticing that $\mu((G-U)g_0)=0$ because of the unimodularity (left and right invariance) of $\mu$) in the Deitmar and Echterhoff's book: Principles of Harmonic Analysis, and Fubini's theorem:

$$0=\int_G f d\mu = \int_{G/\Gamma} \int_{\Gamma} f(g\gamma) d\gamma ~d\nu(g\Gamma) =  \int_{\Gamma}\int_{G/\Gamma} f(g\gamma)d\nu(g\Gamma)~ d\gamma.$$

Since $\Gamma$ is countable, the Haar measure on it must be a scalar multiple of counting measure. So we must have for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$, in particular for $\gamma = e$,

$$0=\int_{G/\Gamma} f(g)d\nu(g\Gamma)= \nu((G-U)g_0 \Gamma).$$

Since $g_0\in G$ is arbitrary, and by the transitivity of the action, $G/\Gamma - Ux$ is contained in $(G-U).x$, we are done.

Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: But professir, aren't all lattices unimodular? Also, I don't really understand the change of order of integration from $d\gamma d\nu(g\Gamma)$ to $d\nu (g\Gamma) d\gamma$. In the last equality of the first equation, what function are you integrating on $G/H$ (the inner integral)?

Comment: @Fancydressfatima  No professor haha...$f=1_{(G-U)g_0}$ is the function I am using. I think that change of order is Fubini theorem?

Comment: @Fancydressfatima For the definition of lattice, I think I have seen some people use one sided invariant probability measure.... but you are right biinvariant thing might be more common

Comment: But I'm still confused about the symbol $\int_{G/\Gamma}f(g\gamma)d\nu(g\Gamma)$. The integrand is the function which sends $g\Gamma \to f(g\gamma)$? What choice of $\gamma$ is being made? How is it well-defined?

Comment: @Fancydressfatima I think the well-definedness is proved in the reference I gave or in Folland's abstract harmonic analysis book, maybe you can take a look to see if this is the case? The function on both sides are the same but there are three different measures. My notations above might be confusing.

Comment: Eh, I don't understand - you're using Fubini's theorem on the space $G/\Gamma \times \Gamma$? On what function?

Comment: I agree with @Latimer's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408223/inherence-of-full-measure-sets-from-a-lie-group-to-its-homogeneous-space/4408649#comment9224525_4408649); I think that it does not make sense to use Fubini's theorem not because of any measure-theoretic subtleties, but because there is no two-variable function here on $G/\Gamma \times \Gamma$, only a one-variable function on $G$ that can, if desired, be averaged over $\Gamma$ to produce another one-variable function on $G/\Gamma$.